# How do I force Django to convert zero in their default DecimalField format into a regular format?

Tags: django, django-models, decimal

I have a very big DecimalField in one of my models.

```
class Price(models.Model):
    min_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=20)
```

So basically, its a huge number, storing upto 20 precision points.

All values seem to work, other than zero that is. Lets say I serialize this field into a json object using the following:

```
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

price = Price.objects.get(pk=1)
json = json.loads(json.dumps({
    "min_value" : price.min_value,
}, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder))
```

For most values, I get the correct decimal numbers in a string format. However, if the min_value is set to 0, I get something like this: `"0E-20"`

I'm pretty sure it means `0.00000000000000000000`, or 20 zeroes after the point. However, I would like to get it in the usual format, or basically this: `"0.00000000000000000000"`.

How do I force DjangoJSONEncoder to do this? Note, I do realize I can easily do this using the string "0E-20", by taking the number after the dash, running a for loop that many times, and generating a string that only contains zeroes. But is there a better, more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's built in JSON encoder just casts the `Decimal` object to string so the fault lies with the stdlib instead.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> x = Decimal('0.00000000000000000000')
>>> x
Decimal('0E-20')
>>> str(x)
'0E-20'
>>> '{:f}'.format(x)
'0.00000000000000000000'
```

From quick tests it seems formatting the decimal as a float works, so try using this custom encoder:

```
import decimal
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

class CustomJSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return '{:f}'.format(o)
        return super().default(o)
```